# Instantiate an object defined in module A and use its methods in module B javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working in a web development project.

Right now i'm using a 3rd party library to instantiate an object of that library in a file called, let's say, fileA.js

so i do:

```
import libraryExport from "./librarymain.js"

var object = libraryExport( ... );
export default object;
```

Now, in fileB.js i want to use the methods that the instantiated object has, for example:

```
import object from "fileA.js"
object.methodOfTheLibrary();
```

However, when im running this in my browser console i always get "methodOfTheLibrary is not a function", which means, from my point of view, that the library is not being imported properly in fileB.js

Note: I'm using webpack to bundle all of my files and everything was compiling and bundling just fine until i came with issues. I usually know my way around C++ in an advanced way but for JS i just still don't fully understand how to solve these kind of import issues.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you tried calling `object.methodOfLibrary()` in `fileA.js`?

Comment: Yes sir. And it works. The thing is that fileA is just a place that i'm using to init 3rd party libraries objects, in FileB there's some flow going on that thriggers that function that i'm trying to use. @zr0gravity7

Comment: You could try `console.log`ging the `object` in your `fileB.js` to see what you actually obtain. Had you successfully managed to export and import object between modules before this with your Webpack setup?

Comment: I'm gonna try that. With my webpack setup i've been doing it but only with custom made methods, variables, etc. This is the first time i do it with 3rd party code

Comment: Ok so i'm printing the object and i'm getting a bunch of the library stuff, however most of the functions that the library offers doesn't seem to be inside the object. the library is intl-phone-input. @zr0gravity7

Answer (score 0):

It's *generally** recommended that you avoid using an imported module directly in the body of another module. (*One of your own modules, that is... as you'll see in a moment, third-party modules are generally fine to use.*)

The big issue is load order. If your `fileA` also imports some other module, which imports another module which then imports `fileB`, then `fileB` will attempt to run and, since `fileA` is still trying to load dependencies, `object` will not actually have been instantiated yet.

You'll either need to carefully review your dependencies to look for just such a loop and then eliminate it **or**, if possible, restructure `fileA` to wrap your code in a function that can be called once the entry point has finished loading (which will guarantee that all other modules have been resolved):

```js
// fileB.js

import object from "fileA.js"

export function init() {
  object.methodOfTheLibrary();
}

// main.js

import init from "fileB.js";

init();
```

* *"generally" meaning that there are plenty of perfectly acceptable situations where it's fine. You just have to mindful of the pitfalls and mitigate against those situations.*

Comment: Yes, this makes sense! I handle this kind of issues with C++ compiler all the time but i'm still a little afraid of JS now that i'm using it in a more professional way! I solved the thing very similar to this answer: i did let export <var_name> = <the_content>; and that did it! now i'm wondering what's the difference on importing a variable on declare and doing it at the end of the file

Comment: @FrankPonte - Not sure what you mean by "_importing a variable on declare_". If you are using standard JS or a bundler like webpack, then imports are "[hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)", meaning that no matter where they appear in your module they will effectively run before any other logic in your module. The order of imports matters, but where they appear in the module doesn't.